# Long lines of text to show in a single line in scrolling text custom HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-element

I wanted to create a scrolling text banner custom HTML element.
And I found the first example that is in this site(https://blog.hubspot.com/website/scrolling-text-css) does very close to what I want to do.

The one problem that I have with above is that if I have a long text (i.e. like a paragraph) so that it goes over the width of the container, I see the text showing in multiple lines so that multiple lines of text scroll at the same time.

I'd like to make it so that a single line of text shows and it scrolls until it shows all the text then repeat the scrolling cycle.  I am guessing it will have to be some css setting that I have to update.  What kind of setting do I need to add or change to make long text to show in a single scrolling line?  Any help will be appreciated.

Below is my custom element .js file that I came up with based on the contents from the site I mentioned above.  It does some extra stuff of taking color and text attributes and applies them, but you can ignore that part.  createStyle() function is where I have the css stuff for styling:

my-scrolling-text-v3.js:

```js
class MyScrollingTextV3CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  attrObj = {
    color: '#000',
    text: 'Please set "text" attribute in the custom element'
  };
  attrs = ['color', 'text'];

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("myScrollingText.constructor()");
    // attributes aren't available in constructor.
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    try {
      console.log("myScrollingText.connectedCallback()");
      this.setAttributes();
      console.log("myScrollingText.connectedCallback(): attrObj=" + JSON.stringify(this.attrObj));
      this.appendChild(this.createStyle(this.attrObj.color));
      this.appendChild(this.createScrollingTextInsideTextContainer(this.attrObj.text));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("myScrollingText.connectedCallback(): catch: " + error);
    }
  }

  setAttributes() {
    let value = "";
    for (let attr of this.attrs) {
      console.log("setAttributes(): attr=" + attr);
      try {
        value = this.getAttribute(attr);
        console.log("setAttributes(): value=" + value);
        if (this.attrObj.hasOwnProperty(attr) && value && (value !== '')) {
          this.attrObj[attr] = value;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // ignore and use default
      }
    }
  }

  createStyle(color) {
    const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.innerHTML = `
                #scroll-container {
                    border: 3px solid black;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
                #scroll-text {
                    font-size: 34px;
                    color: ${color};
                    /* animation properties */
                    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
                    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                    transform: translateX(100%);
                    -moz-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
                    -webkit-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
                    animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
                }
                /* for Firefox */
                @-moz-keyframes my-animation {
                    from { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
                    to { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
                }
                /* for Chrome */
                @-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
                    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
                    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
                }
                @keyframes my-animation {
                    from {
                        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
                        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                        transform: translateX(100%);
                    }
                    to {
                        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
                        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
                        transform: translateX(-100%);
                    }
                }
            `;
    return styleElement;
  }

  createScrollingTextInsideTextContainer(text) {
    const textContainerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    textContainerDiv.id = 'scroll-container';
    textContainerDiv.appendChild(this.createScrollingText(text));
    return textContainerDiv;
  }

  createScrollingText(text) {
    const textDiv = document.createElement('div');
    textDiv.id = 'scroll-text';
    textDiv.textContent = text;
    return textDiv;
  }

}

customElements.define('my-scrolling-text-v3', MyScrollingTextV3CustomElement);
```

```html
<my-scrolling-text-v3 color="#0f0" text="This is the text value from my-scrolling-text-v3 element"></my-scrolling-text-v3>
```

Comment: If you add the css property `white-space` with a value of `nowrap` the text will not wrap when the bounds of the element are reached, instead it will overflow. Couple this with an `overflow-x: auto` and you should have a long scrolling line. Be sure that the element with the overflow is of `display:block` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the `white-space` property suggestion. It does make the text to show in a single line, but with this solution, the text seems to disappear all of sudden before the end of text finishes scrolling if I make the container narrow.

I did find another solution from looking at various samples and trying..  Adding display: flex and flex-shrink: 0 to the container and text did the trick for me like below:
```
  #scroll-container {
   display:flex;
  }

  #scroll-text {
   flex-shrink: 0;
  }
```

And seems to give the exact behavior that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at different css examples and trying different properties, I found the combination of properties that make it behave the way that I want it to.
The trick was to add these two properties:

```
#scroll-container {
    display:flex;
}

#scroll-text {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

And so the final solution with complete code is like below:

```js
class MyScrollingTextV3CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  attrObj = {
    color: '#000',
    text: 'Please set "text" attribute in the custom element'
  };
  attrs = ['color', 'text'];

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("myScrollingText.constructor()");
    // attributes aren't available in constructor.
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    try {
      console.log("myScrollingText.connectedCallback()");
      this.setAttributes();
      console.log("myScrollingText.connectedCallback(): attrObj=" + JSON.stringify(this.attrObj));
      this.appendChild(this.createStyle(this.attrObj.color));
      this.appendChild(this.createScrollingTextInsideTextContainer(this.attrObj.text));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("myScrollingText.connectedCallback(): catch: " + error);
    }
  }

  setAttributes() {
    let value = "";
    for (let attr of this.attrs) {
      console.log("setAttributes(): attr=" + attr);
      try {
        value = this.getAttribute(attr);
        console.log("setAttributes(): value=" + value);
        if (this.attrObj.hasOwnProperty(attr) && value && (value !== '')) {
          this.attrObj[attr] = value;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // ignore and use default
      }
    }
  }

  createStyle(color) {
    const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.innerHTML = `
                #scroll-container {
                    display: flex;
                    border: 3px solid black;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
    
                #scroll-text {
                    font-size: 2em;
                    color: ${color};
                    flex-shrink: 0;
    
                    /* animation properties */
                    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
                    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                    transform: translateX(100%);
    
                    -moz-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
                    -webkit-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
                    animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
                }
    
                /* for Firefox */
                @-moz-keyframes my-animation {
                    from { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
                    to { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
                }
    
                /* for Chrome */
                @-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
                    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
                    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
                }
    
                @keyframes my-animation {
                    from {
                        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
                        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                        transform: translateX(100%);
                    }
                    to {
                        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
                        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
                        transform: translateX(-100%);
                    }
                }
    
            `;
    return styleElement;
  }

  createScrollingTextInsideTextContainer(text) {
    const textContainerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    textContainerDiv.id = 'scroll-container';
    textContainerDiv.appendChild(this.createScrollingText(text));
    return textContainerDiv;
  }

  createScrollingText(text) {
    const textDiv = document.createElement('div');
    textDiv.id = 'scroll-text';
    textDiv.textContent = text;
    return textDiv;
  }

}

customElements.define('my-scrolling-text-v3', MyScrollingTextV3CustomElement);
```

```html
<my-scrolling-text-v3 color="#0f0" text="This is the text value from my-scrolling-text-v3 element"></my-scrolling-text-v3>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is deprecated, but it still works.

A LOT less code and no wrapping

```css
marquee {
  color: #0f0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 34px;
}
```

```html
<marquee>This is the text value from my-scrolling-text-v3 element</marquee>
```

Comment: I read about the marquee, but as it is deprecated, I'd rather not use that.  I did find a solution though..  See my own answer in this post..

Comment: Great and simple. That works for me :)